# Force sort specific data on edit to the bottom not alphabetically

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get my rows to sort appropriately when a change happens.

I'm very new to VBA and have been trying to workshop my code myself but am completely at a loss. I'm working in Excel 2013.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("D1").Sort Key1:=Range("D4"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If

End Sub
```

I got this code to work to push rows alphabetically whenever i change the value (from a drop down) in Column D.  Ideally, i want my code to push anything that says "CLOSED" in Column D to the bottom.  At the very least, i need this code to sort these rows in Z-A whenever something in D changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort list (e.g. `closed,*`), and programmatically set the xlDescending argument so the *closed* will always end up at the bottom of the list. However, this will also sort the remaining rows in an xlDescending order. That may or may not be desirable.

**Option 1: Custom Sort Order**

In the worksheet's private code sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo end_safe
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add2 Key:=Range(Cells(2, "D"), Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)), _
                      SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
                      CustomOrder:="closed,*", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With
            .SetRange Intersect(Range("A:Z"), UsedRange)
            .Header = xlYes
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    End If

end_safe:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

You want *closed* at the bottom of the list so one alternative might be setting a conditional formatting rule to modify the font or background fill for *closed*, then using that DisplayFormat to sort by color with xlDescending. This will push all *closed* to the bottom of the data block without altering the original order of the remaining (i.e. *non-closed*) rows.

**Option 2: Sort by Conditional Formatting DisplayFormat**

In the worksheet's private code sheet:

```
Option Explicit

'manually run this once to quickly add a CFR for 'closed' cells
Private Sub addClosedCFR()

    With Range("D:D")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$D1=""closed""")
            .Font.Color = vbRed   'vbBlack
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo end_safe
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add(Range(Cells(2, "D"), Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)), _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnFontColor, Order:=xlDescending, _
                     DataOption:=xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = vbRed    'vbBlack
            End With
            .SetRange Intersect(Range("A:Z"), UsedRange)
            .Header = xlYes
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    End If

end_safe:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

If you do not want *closed* showing red in column D, change the font color to something more appropriate. I've left vbBlack in comments which is not the same as the default xlAutomatic font color so it would appear unchanged while still permitting the Sort operation.

Your Sort operation will almost assuredly make changes to column D along with the rest of the data block so temporarily disabling events will stop the Worksheet_Change from trying to run on top of itself.